# Поиск нужного содержимого в файлах на хостинге.. программно

Tags: php

Доброго всем времени суток господа

Вопрос частично по программированию, частично относится на 'руткод'.

Есть подключение по FTP к хостингу на котором много файлов. (php/tpl/xml/html..) в разныз папках. Есть так же файл, адрес которого не известен, в котором прописана определенная фраза, и она есть только в нем.. как его найти?

- скачать все файлы, засунуть в notepad++, и далее поиск по всем файлам (умеем, охота большего)
- .. можно с помощью php построить дерево каталогов и перебрать интересующие файлы построчно (плюс в том, что я 'форточник' и мне не надо ставить пингвина)
- а есть ли способы более быстрые? как с помощью кода, так и другие?

p.s. ситуация обычная - сайт в котором миллион файлов, черт знает с какой структурой и каким подключением файлов друг в друга, требуется найти к примеру код => 'testing_glow_fall'. В данный момент скачиваю на ram диск исходник и быстро ищу в нотпаде.. охота как то на хостинге все перебрать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ssh grep "search_regexp" /path/*
```

[image]

Comment: так.. 1 способ есть. а это дело можно как то через php файл запустить? или каким то образом для тех недочеловеков которые сидят на 'форточках' ?

Comment: @mixalef - в PHP есть две команды: [passthru][1] и [exec][2].

[1]: http://www.php.su/functions/?passthru
[2]: http://www.php.su/functions/?exec

Comment: спасибо, воспользуюсь, впишу туда код соответствующий, пойду тестить.

Comment: Ну решение `grep "search_regexp" /path/*` сильно зависит от структуры каталогов. Команда find с -exec grep будет более уместной.